# Is there a way for a Windows tablet— when uploading an image on a website— to prompt to use the camera instead of using the File Explorer?

Tags: html, windows, web-applications, tablet

#### Problem

I'm currently working on a web application that needs to be able to upload images a lot. It is an `<input type="file" name="picture" accept="image/*">` tag. Just like most other tablet or phone, I assumed that users on a Windows tablet— A Dell Venue 10 pro 5055, running on Windows 10 Enterprise in this case— would also be prompted to use the on-device camera or to choose from files. This is unfortunately not the case and makes the application a lot less user-friendly.

#### Tries

I checked this post: [Can you launch the native Camera App from an Html 5 Web App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676036/can-you-launch-the-native-camera-app-from-an-html-5-web-app), the answer stated that using the following tag solved the problem for Android: `<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">`. This did not work for Windows.

The following post did provide an answer but that answer only works on Windows 8.1 unfortunately: [Capturing images in web application on Windows 8.1 tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471561/capturing-images-in-web-application-on-windows-8-1-tablets)

So is there a way to configure the tablet or to change the `<input>` tag in such a way that the user will be prompted to take a picture instead of choosing from an existing file?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42487979/can-html5-camera-inputs-work-on-windows-10-tablets

Comment: @xph, thanks for your reply. I think however that the problem is due to a setting in windows; the tablet is not acting as a tablet but as a desktop, hence, the tablet does not prompt to use the camera.

Comment: If possible, you can configure your tablet to "identify" as one. If you need the "desktop feeling", that's of course not the solution - good luck anyways!

Comment: @xph, do you have any idea on how to achieve that? I could not find the setting.

Comment: There's various methods, some references: 1) [Windows 10: Switch Between Tablet Mode and Desktop Mode](https://www.top-password.com/blog/windows-10-switch-between-tablet-mode-and-desktop-mode/), 2) [How to Enable or Disable Tablet Mode in Windows 10](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/enable-tablet-mode-windows-10), 3) [Turn tablet mode on or off](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027960/windows-10-turn-tablet-mode-on-or-off) _(Microsofts own help site is... well, they try.)_. Hope that helps to change your tablets behaviour and the camera usage as well. You can give it a try!